# Django custom user login, with different types of users

Tags: django

I've got an extended user model that has three boolean variables, indicating what type the user is:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    newField = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isTypeA = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isTypeB = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

i'm also writing a test for a class based view, called typeCheck

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import MyUser
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def typeCheck(User):
    return User.isTypeA

@user_passes_view(typeCheck, login_url='/login')
def typeAView(request):
    ...
```

when I try accessing the view, I get an error saying: 'User' object has no attribute 'isA'. How do I correctly acces the fields of my extended user model? I also tried

```
return User.MyUser.isTypeA
```

but that just returns an error saying: 'User' object has no attribute 'MyUser'

Answer (score 1):

Your `typeCheck` takes `user` and should be `return user.myuser.isTypeA`

Comment: isn't it `user.my_user.isTypeA`?

Comment: Right. This is clarified here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing Python by having a method parameter that is the same as a class you're trying to import, you could remedy this by changing the method argument to be lowercase which also follows pep8 naming convention

```
def typeCheck(user):
    return user.myuser.isTypeA
```